# How can I tell phpunit where the source and tests can be found

Tags: php, phpunit

I am a newbie with phpunit but I need it to test something

So, suppose that have the following folders

```
mainFolder/SRC/x/y/sourceFiles.php
mainFolder/TESTS/x/y/testFiles.php
mainFolder/TESTS/bootstrap.php
```

When I run phpunit mainFolder it tells me:

> Fatal error: Class 'x/y/sourceFile' not found in mainfolder/tests/x/y/testfile.php on line 28

Note that I am a newbie, and I need some help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you running on a Linux/*nix system? If so, check your file paths have the correct casing, as those filesystems are case-sensitive, Windows is not.

Answer (score 0):

The test files should be able to find the tested classes. Which means you have to require them, or set up a proper autoloading mechanism or pre-load them in a bootstrap file. And probably there are lots of other ways to do this. The test files behave exactly the same in this sense like simple php files.

Comment: The test files have the roots until a point when src/test is different. Is there any way to tell the tests where to look for the class?

Comment: BTW, I'm working on Windows, and I need some kind of reference to this kind of things. Can anyone help?